# Measure Qt Application Performance

Tags: performance, qt, arm

I am working an a Qt application (C++ and QML hybrid, Qt 4.8.4) that I cross-compile and then deploy on an ARM target (runs with the -qws option). Since I am using different targets, and that I have to make a comparison of these targets based on their performances, I would like to test the performances of my application on each of these targets.

I was thinking about measuring the FPS of my application, but I don't know how to do so.

If it's the proper way to make such a test, how do I implement it? If there's a better and/or simpler way to do so, I would be glad hearing about it :)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A typical application models a 3d world and *physics* happen in the model.  When a model update happens, the perspective view is rendered.  This process is timed and feed back to the *physics* model so that the rendering appears to be real time.  The process time is the **FPS** value.  It depends on your model.  Alternatively, you can fix the *physics* delta and just have the model run in *non-realtime*; this is like *glxgears*.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Benchmarking capability of `QTestLib` can help you measuring the performance of your application. Using it, you can test different modules of your application and identify potential performance bottlenecks. See [documentation and example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtestlib-tutorial5.html).

This solution can also measure FPS of your application, as described in the [QTest Namespace](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qttestlib/qtest.html#QBenchmarkMetric-enum).

As a bonus, you can use `QTest` to run your Unit Tests on your devices, which could be great to potentially detect missing OS features on top of regular testing...